# `filterM` for containers like `Data.Map.Map`, or `Data.Set.Set`

Tags: haskell

In short: How would you filter elements of a `Map`, or `Set` on a monadic
predicate in Haskell?

I could think of two possible ways:

a) Round-trip through a list and `filterM` (probably not very efficient):

```
filterMapM1 :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (v -> m Bool) -> M.Map k v -> m (M.Map k v)
filterMapM1 f m = liftM M.fromList $ filterM (f.snd) $ M.toList m
```

b) If the predicate is not inherently monadic, but e.g. is a comparison to the
   state in a `State` monad; then we can use `Data.Map.filter` (quite a special
   case):

```
filterMapM2 :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (v -> v -> Bool) -> M.Map k v -> StateT v m (M.Map k v)
filterMapM2 f m = do
    s <- get
    return $ M.filter (f s) m
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Here's a little example program for demonstration.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map as M

-- | filterM for M.Map. (Round trip through a list and filterM)
filterMapM1 :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (v -> m Bool) -> M.Map k v -> m (M.Map k v)
filterMapM1 f m = liftM M.fromList $ filterM (f.snd) $ M.toList m

-- | filterM for M.Map. (Uses M.filter to filter on comparison to state)
filterMapM2 :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (v -> v -> Bool) -> M.Map k v -> StateT v m (M.Map k v)
filterMapM2 f m = do
    s <- get
    return $ M.filter (f s) m

-- | Inherently monadic predicate: Result depends on user-input.
askUser :: Int -> IO Bool
askUser n = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Do you like the number " ++ show n ++ "?"
    liftIO $ (=="yes") <$> getLine

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let m = M.fromList $ take 6 $ zip ['a'..] [1..]
    -- Use inherently monadic predicate
    print =<< filterMapM1 askUser m
    -- Compare to state
    (`evalStateT` 4) $ do
        filt2 <- filterMapM2 (/=) m
        liftIO $ print filt2
```

---

**Update**: I did a benchmark between different implementations of `filterMapM`. It turns out that the round-trip through a list is actually pretty good. Surprisingly, it did even better than an implementation right on the internal structure of `Map`. The code and data are available [here](https://github.com/aherrmann/HaskellMapFilterM).

Comment: Going trough a list isn't that bad; in the cases of trees you'll most probably have to rebuild the structure if you remove some top-level nodes.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html ?

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Can you elaborate? I don't see how to use these to drop elements straight-forwardly. The only way that comes to mind is an intermediate step through `Maybe`. E.g. use `mapM` on a function `f :: a -> m (Maybe a)`, and then filter all the `Nothing`s out, and use `fromJust` to get rid of the `Maybe`. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I aggree it's not a one-liner. This is about writing shorter/nicer code (or is it about efficiency)? I'm sure there's some construction that involves a lens-ified traversal using `sans` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.5/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:sans to remove elements (from the `At` instance of `Data.Map`).

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 *This is about writing shorter/nicer code (or is it about efficiency)?* I'm not very experienced in Haskell. So, you could say I'm looking for the right™ way. But I'm not so sure if traversing the data twice ("toMaybe", "fromJust") is more efficient than the round trip through a list. *a lens-ified traversal using sans* Case in point: I had no idea of the lens package. But, this seems like a very useful tool to have in general. Thanks for pointing me there. I guess I found something to do for this weekend. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two approaches have quite different semantics and implications for efficiency.

When you round-trip through a list you are allowing the filtering to be affected by all of the previous comparisons, and so the final result could be affected by the order in which the elements are visited. In the second case, however, the filtering is a pure function, so the answer will be the same no matter in what order the comparisons are made.

For instance, the user answering the questions might want to keep the number of even and odd numbers roughly the same, and thus whether the user likes a particular number will depend on all of the numbers that have been presented before.

On the other hand, here is the code for `M.filter`:

```
-- | /O(n)/. Filter all elements that satisfy the predicate.
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set a
filter _ Tip = Tip
filter p (Bin _ x l r)
    | p x       = link x (filter p l) (filter p r)
    | otherwise = merge (filter p l) (filter p r)
```

The important thing is note that shape of the code - the resulting tree structure is greatly influenced by the structure of the original tree. Perhaps only a small amount of rebalancing will be needed. This could be a lot more efficient than rebuilding the tree from zero knowledge using `M.fromList`.

The upshot is that in the `filterM1` case you should be concerned about the order in which the comparisons are made. Perhaps `M.toList` gives an acceptable ordering, or perhaps you want `reverse . M.toList`, or ...

In the second case you don't need to care so you can let `M.filter` do all of the work and take advantage of its knowledge of the data structure.

Update: I just noticed the `M.toAscList` and `M.fromAscList` functions, so perhaps this version of `filterMapM1` is slightly more efficient:

```
filterMapM1 f m = liftM M.fromAscList $ filterM (f.snd) $ M.toAscList m
```

Comment: I did a benchmark (see update) and it turns out that `toList`, and `toAscList` do equally well; and surprisingly better than an implementation right on the internal representation of `Map`. I don't know why, though.

Comment: About the different semantics. Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out. I would argue, though, that if order matters then one should not use a Map, but rather something ordered, like a list, right away.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I don't think there is a more general abstraction that would directly support `filterM`.  Traversable doesn't, because `traverse` can't change the shape of the structure.  I think it is technically possible to do this with lens, however the documentation suggests that you really shouldn't do so and I think it round-trips through another structure anyway.

You could use something like this (uncompilable because `filter` is not a class member):

```
filterM :: (Traversable c, Monad m, Applicative m) => (a -> m Bool) -> c a -> m (c a)
filterM p = fmap snd . filter fst . traverse p'
  where p' x = (,x) <$> p x
```

whether this is more or less efficient than round-tripping through a list probably depends on the structure.  It's arguably less clean.

Comment: I had a look at lense but couldn't quite figure out a nice way of doing this. As you say, it doesn't seem to be what lens is primarily designed for. I did a small benchmark (see update) and the round-trip through the list is doing pretty well.